# Simmetric complex matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I must show a counter example to the sentence "every simmetric complex matrix is diagonalizable." But Im having issues on guessing one of them. Can someone help me?

Comment: What conditions are you trying?

Comment: Im trying to find a 2x2 matrice whose characteristic polynomial is a perfect square

Comment: Ooh just got it, thank you anyway :)

Comment: Usually if there is a counterexample, there is one of order $2\times2$.

Comment: Great! In the future, you should post your solution so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have found a counterexample, I can give you a full answer now. Just try this:
$$
A=\pmatrix{i&1\\ 1&-i}.
$$
Since $A$ is nonzero but $A^2=0$, $A$ is not diagonalisable.

The statement that "every complex symmetric matrix is diagonalisable" is certainly false, because *every complex square matrix is similar to a complex symmetric matrix*. (See Theorem 2.1.4 of [Olga Ruff's Master thesis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.146.5519&rep=rep1&type=pdf&ei=V5iwUbLpMKjqiAfUz4GIBw&usg=AFQjCNHqEzlqYg0TeKHm8T5dADzT_rk9aQ&sig2=8c9JE1WpQghj3i-D3w_WRg&bvm=bv.47534661,d.aGc), for instance.)

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample $\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
1&2i\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Minimal polynomial is $(x-i)^2$ so the matrix is not diagonalizable(as the minimal polynomial of all diagonalizable matrices is always the product of distinct linear factors).